# Import project from git - ready api

Tags: soapui, ready-api

I'm trying to import myself into a ready api 2.2.0 project from GIT, but after entering the below I get what's on the screen.
When I enter the folder that I have created, a .git folder is created
Is it possible to somehow get rid of this folder not added?
I also have a Git Integration Plugin 1.0.2 plugin

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly same issue and version of Ready API was 2.2.0. The problem was a bug in this particular version of git plugin for Ready API (1.0.2). I fixed it by manually uploading 1.1.0 version of the jar in Plugins tab and restarted Ready API. It worked.
However, I would not recommend using Ready API for version control. I simply cannot trust it. I have had way too many reliability issues with their software in general.
My suggestion is to use GitBash or something similar. In this case there is no need to make your project composite. 
If you will have any merging conflicts the best/easiest way I know of to fix those is using IntelliJ Idea's UI. Just Import the project and resolve them one by one.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe the message says it all. Did you check if the directory you're saving to exists and is indeed empty?

Comment: My folder is not empty. I wrote that I create an empty folder, I give the path to it and press the Confirm button and then this message appears when confirming. Then I go to the folder and see that a .git folder is created

Comment: But the problem is that it's not empty. Also, it needs to exist. This seems trivial, but if the software can't access it, because of permissions mostly, then it doesn't exist, as long as the application is concerned. Check, please, if the directory is readable and writable.

Answer (score 0):

This same problem also created with me...The solution to this problem is default branch. You have to set your default branch to be master branch first after that go to the: C>User>Administrator>.soapUI>plugins then delete 2 of the jar file if present there "ready-api-git-plugin-1.1.0.jar" and "ready-api-git-plugin-1.0.1.jar"and restart you readyAPI again Now you able to clone the project from git successfully.
Hope this will work for you lemme know